# MaskedTextBox set SelectionStart when it get focused by Tab key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a MaskedTextBox. I set SelectionStart to 2, since it need to start from there. I did it in Onclick event as follow

```
private void maskedTextBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox2.ReadOnly = false;
    maskedTextBox2.Text = "";
    maskedTextBox2.SelectionStart=8;
}
```

And it work good when I click on the MaskedtextBox. But when i use Tab and maskedtexbox get focused by Tab and not by click, SelectionStart is the default. How to manage this? How to force  "maskedTextBox2.SelectionStart=8;" when maskedtextbox get focused by Tab and not by click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `Click` event use the `Enter` event. You can find the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter?view=netcore-3.1).

```
private void maskedTextBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        maskedTextBox2.ReadOnly = false;
        maskedTextBox2.Text = "";
        maskedTextBox2.SelectionStart=8;
    }
```

Now the code will be executed whenever the `MaskedTextBox` is entered, which is done when the user tabs to the textbox or click on it.